How to send remote notification between two users using expo
I am using expo with firebase and clerk, I want to create a listing transfer system in which some one would create a listing and other could request that product. I want to push the notification when someone request the transfer to the user that created the listing. I am using expo but it is making a local notification instead of remote notification.
I have tried to send notification but it is only working locally,
      await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: notificationContent,
        trigger: null,
      });

